# Spring Integration DSL KafkaProducerContext configuration

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, spring-dsl

I am trying to adapt the following example:
https://github.com/joshlong/spring-and-kafka

with latest stable versions of the following libraries:

```
org.apache.kafka > kafka_2.10 > 0.8.2.2
org.springframework.integration > spring-integration-kafka > 1.2.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.integration > spring-integration-java-dsl > 1.1.0.RELEASE
```

The integration dsl library seems to have gone through a refactoring probably driven by the introduction of the new KafkaProducer.

Here is the code of my Producer configuration:

```
@Bean(name = OUTBOUND_ID)
IntegrationFlow producer() {
    log.info("starting producer flow..");

    return flowDefinition -> {
        ProducerMetadata<String, String> getProducerMetadata = new ProducerMetadata<>(this.kafkaConfig.getTopic(),
                    String.class, String.class, new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer());


        KafkaProducerMessageHandler kafkaProducerMessageHandler = Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(props ->
                props.put("timeout.ms", "35000"))
                .messageKey(m -> m.getHeaders().get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER))
                .addProducer(getProducerMetadata, this.kafkaConfig.getBrokerAddress())
                .get();

        flowDefinition
                .handle(kafkaProducerMessageHandler);
    };
}
```

And the code for message generation:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn(OUTBOUND_ID)
CommandLineRunner kickOff(@Qualifier(OUTBOUND_ID + ".input") MessageChannel in) {
    return args -> {              
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            in.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("#" + i).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, this.kafkaConfig.getTopic()).build());
                log.info("sending message #" + i);
        }
    };
}
```

Thats the exception I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:287)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:245)
at jc.DemoApplication$ProducerConfiguration.lambda$kickOff$0(DemoApplication.java:104)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:673)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext.getTopicConfiguration(KafkaProducerContext.java:67)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaProducerContext.send(KafkaProducerContext.java:201)
at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:88)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
... 18 more
```

UPDATE:
The full working source can be found in my fork:
https://github.com/magiccrafter/spring-and-kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for delay.

Your problem is around the early `IntegrationComponentSpec` instantiation:

```
KafkaProducerMessageHandler kafkaProducerMessageHandler = Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(props ->
          props.put("timeout.ms", "35000"))
          .messageKey(m -> m.getHeaders().get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER))
          .addProducer(getProducerMetadata, this.kafkaConfig.getBrokerAddress())
          .get();
```

you should not call `.get()` yourself. 
The `KafkaProducerMessageHandlerSpec` is `ComponentsRegistration` and only SI Java DSL can resolve it correctly. The code there looks like:

```
public Collection<Object> getComponentsToRegister() {
    this.kafkaProducerContext.setProducerConfigurations(this.producerConfigurations);
    return Collections.<Object>singleton(this.kafkaProducerContext);
}
```

Since this code isn't invoked the `this.producerConfigurations` isn't populated to the `this.kafkaProducerContext`. Although the last one must be registered as a bean anyway.

So, to fix your problem you should deal only with the `IntegrationComponentSpec` in DSL definition.

Just obtain the `KafkaProducerMessageHandlerSpec` and use it for the `.handle()` below. Not sure if there is a reason to extract this object if we can use `Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter()` directly from the `.handle()`.

Comment: I've already solved it, but I didn't know how the things work under the hood. Thanks a lot for the SDL, the answer and the complete explanation.